# Pycharm python AttributeError: module 'urllib3' has no attribute 'Request'

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, pycharm, urllib

When I run script I get this error:

AttributeError: module 'urllib3' has no attribute 'Request'

How to install/import urllib properly to run this script?

Here's some code:

```
import urllib3
import csv
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

rank_page = 'https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/50/mostviewed'
request = urllib3.Request(rank_page, headers={'User-Agent': 'your user-agent'})
page = urllib3.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

channels = soup.find('div', attrs={'style': 'float: right; width: 900px;'}).find_all('div', recursive=False)[4:]

file = open('topyoutubers.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(file)

# write title row
writer.writerow(['Username', 'Uploads', 'Views'])

for channel in channels:
    username = channel.find('div', attrs={'style': 'float: left; width: 350px; line-height: 25px;'}).a.text.strip()
    uploads = channel.find('div', attrs={'style': 'float: left; width: 80px;'}).span.text.strip()
    views = channel.find_all('div', attrs={'style': 'float: left; width: 150px;'})[1].span.text.strip()

    print
    username + ' ' + uploads + ' ' + views
    writer.writerow([username.encode('utf-8'), uploads.encode('utf-8'), views.encode('utf-8')])

file.close()
```

Comment: the error is as clear as day, in short it is saying that you can't do this: `urllib3.Request`, that is it, nothing more, it is simply not possible to do that, don't think that it is an installation problem, more that you may have mistyped sth or that you were looking at an outdated documentation

Answer (score 0):

It seem attribute 'Request' only work in Python2. Just use:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlopen(url, headers)
```